# Weakest assumption for pointwise convergence of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

This should be a quick one, but so far books, my brain, and the internet have not produced a clear answer.  Or maybe it's subtle and exposes a weakness in my understanding of FS!

Suppose $f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c_ke^{ikx}$, whereby we mean pointwise convergence.  What properties must $f(x)$ then satisfy?  Clearly continuity is too strong (take for example an appropriately defined square wave).  $L^1[-\pi,\pi]$ seems troublesome as well, since term-by-term integration is not necessarily valid with only pointwise convergence.

Thanks ahead for any tips!

Comment: Eh? You should first define what ambient class of functions you want $f$ to belong to, presumably you want $L^1$ since otherwise one has trouble even defining the Fourier coefficients. Then it sounds like you are asking what can be said about integrable functions $f$ whose Fourier series converge pointwise.

Comment: @Yemon, what's wrong about the ambient class being all functions $S^1\to\mathbf{C}$? Therein the poster wants to characterize the set of all pointwise limits of pointwise convergent Fourier series. 

Comment: Francois, how is one proposing to define the Fourier coefficients of $f$? Or is the question: "here is a doubly infinite series $(c_n)$ of complex numbers, such that for each $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$ the partial sums $\sum_{|k|\lq N} c_k e^{ikx}$ converge; what can we say about the resulting function $f:[-\pi,\pi] \to {\mathbb C}$?"

Comment: As stated it seems that the question is not
related to Fourier series or $L^1$, or any other a priori given class
of functions.
He seems to ask: suppose that SOME series of the form
$\sum c_k\exp(ikx)$ is convergent at every point. What can one say
about the sum? Do I understand correctly? 

Comment: The context of the question was that of Fourier series, but I think the restatement by @Alexandre is appropriate. 

Comment: It may bear emphasis that various possible senses of the question have wildly different, and not strongly related, answers, and that some bit of confusion about this is evident in the question's language and form. E.g., the Fourier series of a square wave, or other piecewise smooth, but not smooth, function converges not-so-well at the discontinuity. Meanwhile, yes, of course $L^1$ has problems, its problems are arguably less severe than "mere pointwise-valued functions". (Francois Ziegler's cited survey paper is very interesting in the regard of to-me-pathologies, nevertheless!)

Clarify?

Comment: I find the question clear enough ; there's no confusion when the poster discusses the $L^1$ or a precise class of functions since quite plainly the text is structured like this:

(1) what are the properties one can expect from the sum of a Fourier-looking series?

(2) one can notice that those and those properties can't hold because the theory of Fourier series already provides sufficient counter-examples (this is where the text discusses class of functions, as examples guiding the discussion and not as part of the question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function must be integrable in a certain sense defined by Denjoy and others. Here is an interesting [survey paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1955-09853-7) on the subject:

> One of the problems in the theory of trigonometric series
>   $$\frac12a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx)\tag{1.1}$$ is that of suitably defining a trigonometric integral with the property that, if the series (1.1) converges everywhere to a function $f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is necessarily integrable and the coefficients, $a_n$ and $b_n$, given in the usual Fourier form. It is well known that a series may converge everywhere to a function which is not Lebesgue summable nor even Denjoy integrable (...) The problem has been solved by Denjoy [4; 5], Verblunsky [14],
>   Marcinkiewicz and Zygmund [10], Burkill [1; 2], and James [8]. (...) The solutions are described, mainly in the order in which they were published, in §§2-7 below.

Comment: Excellent reference, thank you.  It appears that the answer is not entirely straightforward, which is good (I thought about this for a while before asking).